# How do I allow a user to post an item directly to their facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I'm creating a site that has images and video behind a login. I'd like the user to be able to share an asset but the can't share the url since you have to be logged in to see it. I know I can create an app that has the user connect their facebook to my site that will in turn allow the to post the asset directly to their page saving it to their photo and video albums.

Problems is, I can't quite figure out how to do it. I have the Facebook Dev documentation pulled up: [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

However, I can't figure out how to add a "post to facebook" button that would allow the user to connect and share the asset without requiring a URL to the item itself.

Does anyone know of a tutorial or a great resource to get me started?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but why would you want to share a page hidden by login on Facebook?

Comment: I don't want to share the page, just an image. The images are user generated (customized) but they must be logged in to view the items. I need the user to be able to share their image without having to share the page/item that is behind the login. I've seen this done many times, I just can't find any resources to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Any way you could share just the image resource outside of a login? You could also just dynamically generate a resource whenever an image is shared.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your image directory to be accessible outside of your secure area you can use the Facebook sharer url.  You will only have to share the url of the created image not a url to any actual page.

This is the link your share button would go to:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://zef.me/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/funny-cat.jpg

Example for building link or button:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url to image}" target="_blank">
 Share on Facebook
</a>
```